# the back button not changing in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i have to change the back button image. So for achieveing this i am using the following code:

```
       //add the back button.
    UIButton *home = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];  
    UIImage *homeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];  
    [home setBackgroundImage:homeImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
    [home addTarget:self action:@selector(cancel:)  
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  
    home.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30); 
    UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]  
                                      initWithCustomView:home] autorelease];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = cancelButton;
```

also the method cancel defined in this view controller. I use the above code in viewDidLoad method. I am still not able to see the back button. No button shows up in the navigation bar.

I am writing this code in the viewcontroller that is loaded, and not in the previous view.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set it as *leftBarButtonItem*.

```
self.leftBarButtonItem.backBarButtonItem = cancelButton;
```

Comment: thank you, also can i change the image of the navigation bar?

Comment: @user590849, Go through this page, http://blog.whitepeaksoftware.com/2010/09/11/customizing-the-look-of-uinavigationbar-and-uinavigationcontroller/

Comment: ok, once i make this class, how do i set the custom navigation class as the navigation bar for my application. i am using a navigation based application template.